# ffmpeg concat video and image issue

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have a video it's 190 seconds long. 
I want to show a part of the video with audio and a watermark (from 28th second to 154th second) 
and then the video fades out, and then show an image for 5 seconds at the end of the video.

everything was working fine until i added concat and endpic.jpg

Here is the script it wrote but it's not working. It's really driving me crazy.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 28 -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i watermark.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i endpic.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[1]fade=in:st=3:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=20:d=1:alpha=1[w]; [0][w]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[sonh];[sonh]fade=out:st=154:d=1[sonhh];[sonhh:v][sonhh:a][2:v][3:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -t 155 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Comment: 28**th** seconds starts with `-ss 27` and 154**th** seconds ends with `-to 154`. Or do you mean 29th second and 155th seconds?

Comment: Hello Gyan, the timing works the way I need but I’m having problem with merging it with endpic.jpg part :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 28 -to 154 -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -t 22 -i watermark.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i endpic.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[1]fade=in:st=3:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=20:d=1:alpha=1[w]; [0][w]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10,fade=out:st=154:d=1[sonhh];[sonhh][0:a][2:v][3:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -t 155 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

If you don't limit the input duration, ffmpeg will feed till 190s of the input, and due to `-t 155`, the output will never get to the end of the input and the start of endpic.

Linklabels assigned within a filtergraph don't represent the original inputs so `[sonhh:v][sonhh:a]` isn't valid. The input audio remains `[0:a]`.

Input `-to` was added a few months ago, so ensure you're using a recent build of ffmpeg.

Comment: Hi Gyan, it only creates an 0KB output.mp4 file :(
even tho all of input files are placed in the right place

Comment: You will have to share the full log.

Comment: `endpic` has to be the same resolution as the video!